# Problema al ejecutar función con Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

soy relativamente nuevo con php y me estoy encontrando con un problema. Tengo un formulario con html en el que al pulsar un botón, se ejecuta una función ajax que pasa un valor que recojo luego en php y ejecuta un switch que segun el valor pasado por ajax llama a una función de php. El problema es que no logro que funcione.

este es el codigo javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#botonGrabar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: "../programa.php",
       method: "POST",
       async: false,
       data: {funcion: 1},
       success: function() { }
     });
  });  
 });
```

Este es el contenido del archivo php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["funcion"])) {
    $funcion = $_POST['funcion'];
    switch($funcion) { 
        case 1:
            grabar_datos();
            break;
        default:
            echo "Error";
    }
}


include('db_acceso.php');

/*abre la conexion con la base de datos*/
function conexion(){
    //conexion con el servidor mysql y seleccion de la base de datos:
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

    #compruebo la conexion, en caso de error salgo
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect error:".$mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    return $mysqli;
}

/*metodo para grabar los datos introducidos en la bd*/
function grabar_datos(){
    $mysqli =conexion();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into libros (nombre,isbn,año,autor) values(?,?,?,?)") or die($mysqli->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssis",$_POST['nombreLibro'],$_POST['isbn'],$_POST['año'],$_POST['autor']);
    //ejecutamos
    $stmt->execute() or die($mysqli->error);
    // Cerramos la sentencia preparada.
    $stmt -> close();
    // Cerramos la conexión.
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

?>

Gracias por adelantado.
un saludo

Comment: Hola Gabriel, podrías indicar que parte no funciona? llega el ajax al archivo? no guarda en base de datos?  te da algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Tienes que recuperar la respuesta del servidor en la parte del `success` y mostrarla en alguna parte, un contenedor del HTML por ejemplo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#botonGrabar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: "../programa.php",
       method: "POST",
       async: false,
       data: {funcion: 1},
       success: function(response) 
                { 
                   alert(response); //manejar respuesta
                }
     });
  });  
 });
```

La respuesta se recupera así en el `success`. Si observas, he agregado a la función un parámetro `response` que sería lo que devuelva el servidor mediante  cualquier salida por pantalla.

Dentro del bloque del `success` yo puse un `alert` sólo para que veas si muestra algo, luego eso tienes que manejarlo, según lo que quieras hacer con la información que devuelva el servidor.

También, en el código PHP, debes emitir alguna información desde `grabar_datos()` cuando el `execute` sea exitoso. Esa parte está silenciada y por tanto no habrá respuesta en ese caso.

Puedes modificarlo así:

```
function grabar_datos(){
    $mysqli =conexion();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into libros (nombre,isbn,año,autor) values(?,?,?,?)");         
    $stmt->bind_param("ssis",$_POST['nombreLibro'],$_POST['isbn'],$_POST['año'],$_POST['autor']);
    //ejecutamos
    if ( $stmt && $stmt->execute() ){
        $msg= "Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->affected_rows;
        // Cerramos la sentencia preparada.
        $stmt -> close();
    } else {
        $msg=$stmt->error;
    }
    echo $msg;
    // Cerramos la conexión.
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

He evitado tantos `die`, prefiriendo un estilo más conforme a la programación actual<sup>1</sup> que consiste en ir controlando el flujo de datos y recogiendo en una variable `$msg`, la cual es impresa al final de todo.

---

1. Podemos decir que programar usando constantemente `die()`, `exit()` ... aunque el Manual de PHP conserva todavía muchos ejemplos así, es una herencia antigua. Es más preferible controlar el flujo del código teniendo un sólo punto de salida y no varios. Esta es una práctica que viene de una concepción exclusivamente procedural de la programación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las sugerencias y por la bienvenida, gracias a esto acabo de comprender como funciona ajax, que de hecho me faltaba recoger los valores del formulario y pasárselos al archivo php cuando se ejecuta.  Voy a modificar el primer post con la solución por si le ayuda a alguien mas.

Comment: @gabriel1995 Ojo, Stackoverflow no funciona como los foros. Es un sitio de preguntas / respuestas. Tú planteas la pregunta y otros responden. No deberías modificar ahora la pregunta poniendo una respuesta. El sitio está pensando para que lo que preguntas pueda servir a otros con el mismo problema. Pero cuando alguien entra buscando ayuda se fija sobre todo en la respuesta, no en la pregunta. Por favor l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: Error de novato, lo siento. Ya e modificado el primer post para dejarlo como estaba.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy tratando de usar ajax y un select option para buscar valores en una tabla y traerlos para colocarlos en campos inputs.

Este es el select input:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="series" id="series"  >
                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Eliga documento...</option>
                            <?php
                                $query="SELECT id_serie as id, nro_serie, descripcion_serie FROM series_tipdoc WHERE status_sertipdoc = '0'";                                   
                                $sql_tipodocumento=mysqli_query($con, $query);                                                              
                                while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_tipodocumento)){
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $rows['nro_serie'].' '.$rows['descripcion_serie']; ?></option>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
```

Este es el getData.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#series").change(function() {    
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'serie='+ id;
        console.log(dataString);
        //alert( this.value );
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "./ajax/autocomplete/buscar_tabla_numeracion.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                //$("#display").html(data);
               //if(employeeData) {
                    //$("#heading").show();       
                    //$("#no_records").hide();                  
                    $("#id_tipodoc").text(data.id_tipodoc);
                    $("#abreviado").text(data.abreviado);
                    $("#descripcion_serie").text(data.descripcion_serie);
                    $("#nro_serie").text(data.nro_serie);
                    $("#tabla").text(data.tabla);
                    $("#sec_numeracion").text(data.sec_numeracion);                 
                    $("#cant_digitos").text(data.cant_digitos); 
 
                //} else {
                    //$("#heading").hide();
                //} 

            }
        });


    }) 
});
```

Este es el php que busca la información para devolver al ajax:*texto en itálica*

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
include("../../config/db.php");
include("../../config/conexion.php");
$return_arr = array();
/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($con)
{
    //$sql = "SELECT id, nombre_personal, salario_personal, edad_personal FROM personal WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
    //$sql = "SELECT id_serie, nro_serie, descripcion_serie FROM series_tipdoc WHERE id_serie='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
    $sql = "SELECT td.id_tipodoc, td.abreviado, st.descripcion_serie, st.nro_serie,td.tabla, st.sec_numeracion, st.cant_digitos FROM series_tipdoc AS st INNER JOIN tipo_documento AS td on td.id_tipodoc = st.id_tipodoc 
    WHERE td.status_tipo_documento = '0' AND st.id_serie ='".$_POST['serie']."'";   
    
    $resultset = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($con));
    
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}

?>
```

Gracias.